# VB.Net Sending Email Using Gmail OAuth-2

Tags: .net, vb.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, gmail

We have some XP users and we can't go higher than framework 4.0
Currently we have an email client using the system.net.mail class.
We want to use Oauth2 with gmail when sending an email.
This email can have attachments and multiple recipients.
We have made this in vb.net.

I have been searching on the web to make this happen but can't find an easy solution.

I need some help to send an email using Oauth2 via Gmail using vb.net 4.0.

I know this has probably been asked before, if so please give me a link to their post. I thought tho that the question was more specific to my needs and may be different than others.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't use oauth2 this is the system.new.mail thanks tho

Comment: check this : -http://code.pearson.com/pearson-learningstudio/apis/authentication/authentication-sample-code/sample-code-oauth-2-vbnet_x and this : -https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth